# How to divide in LaTeX without it rounding or truncating?

Tags: latex

I'm working on a diagram and pretty new to LaTeX, so I've decided to try to do it using math instead of statically assigned values. I have come up with the following:

```
\newcommand\qoffset{14}
\newcommand\smallx{8}
\newcommand\smally{4}
\newcommand\py{\the\numexpr\smally * (\qoffset / (\qoffset - \smallx))}
\the\numexpr\qoffset / (\qoffset - \smallx)
```

The answer should be 9.3 for \py but the division is rounding (or truncating) and I need decimal point precision. How would I go about doing this?

NOTE: I am not dead set on using `\the\numexpr`, it's just what I found when trying to figure out how to do math.

Comment: you probably want to ask it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Please make a [mre] instead of a code fragment. Are you maybe looking for the `xfp` package?